# Python EasyGUI: How to get a scroll bar inside multienterbox

Tags: python, scrollbar, easygui

I want to have a simple gui program to edit a python dictionary, so naturally [EasyGUI](http://easygui.sourceforge.net/) is my first choice. My problem is that my dictionary is long, `{key1:v1,key2:v2,...,keyn:vn}`, and when I enter the following code:

```
multienterbox(label,title,[key1,key2,...,keyn])
```

the window is not big enough to display all my keys.

Is there a way to add a scroll bar to the window or any workaround is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `choicebox` which displays the keys and their values.  The user can then select the key they want to change, and you can use an `enterbox` to get the new value.

More info [here](http://easygui.sourceforge.net/tutorial/index.html#contents_item_11.3).